# "something to remove" vs "something to be removed"

Tags: grammaticality

Let's bring a sentence here, "You do not know that I love you", and I want to remove a word, "that". When describing this, which is correct to say "*that* is a word to be removed" or "*that* is a word to remove"?

"something to remove" vs "something to be removed"

Comment: Both are correct to me.

Comment: It can go both ways, and is an element of my writing **that** I'm always playing around with.

Comment: It can go both ways, and is an element of my writing I'm always playing around with. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is **that word can be removed** is a passive voice structure. But **that word to remove** sounds grammatically wrong. Instead, I can say, *This word is difficult to remove, It's amazing to learn, It's difficult to learn, It's too close to handle.....etc* here the *to+Vinf.* post-modifies the adjective phrase.